# Why is the "Process ID" counter in ".NET CLR Memory" category constantly zero?

Tags: .net, process, clr, performancecounter, perfmon

Under the "**.NET CLR Memory**" performance counter category, there is a counter named "**Process ID**". Any given instance of this counter is supposed to return the Process Id of the Windows process associated with the instance. For my own processes, this counter always has a zero value. Why is that?

If I look at the `devenv` instance of the counter, it returns the expected value - at least, the value matches the process id reported by Task Manager.

If I run my own application in Debug mode and examine the `PerfCounterTest.vshost` instance of the counter, it only ever has the value zero.

If I run my own application without the debugger, the `PerfCounterTest` instance is always zero.

If I run several instances of my own application, the sequence-numbered instances `PerfCounterTest#1`, `PerfCounterTest#2` ... all have the value zero.

Why is this counter always zero and, seeing as it is always zero, how do I find the instance-name associated with my process, bearing in mind that it may not have a unique name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens, an instance of this counter will have the value zero until the first garbage collection occurs in the process associated with that instance.

This fact is documented in the *counter help* text associated with the "**Process ID**" counter:

> This counter displays the process ID of the CLR process instance being monitored. The value displayed will be 0 until after the first garbage collection.

The obscurity stems from the fact that, while you can easily read this text using stuff in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, there is no other documentation on the matter. I searched the MSDN, TechNet and the web and found nothing. Even after discovering the answer, I opened up *PerfMon* and tried to find this string in the U.I. - to the best of my knowledge, it is not displayed anywhere.

For future reference, here's how you interrogate the *counter help* text:

```
using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
    using (PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter(".NET CLR Memory", "Process ID", process.ProcessName, true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(performanceCounter.CounterHelp);
    }
}
```